# How to correctly convert NaN to NA

Tags: r, nan, na

On a given double vector, how come I can define `-999` to `NA` by

```
v[v == -999] <- NA
```

but not

```
v[v == NaN] <- NA
```

and how do I convert `NaN`'s to `NA`'s correctly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`==` doesn't work for testing `NA` and `NaN` values. This is good because, from a data perspective, two missing values may or may not be the same. Use `is.na()` and `is.nan()` to test for those.

What you want is `v[is.nan(v)] <- NA`

You can find details in the help pages at `?NaN` and `?NA`.

This is mentioned on the help pages, but it's worth pointing out that `NaN` is treated as a special type of `NA`, so we get this behavior:

```
> is.na(NaN)
[1] TRUE

> is.nan(NA)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: thanks! Follow up question: What would be the approach for lists?

Comment: Nothing special about `NA` or `NaN` in a list. Use `lapply`, `sapply`, `[[`, a for loop, whatever you would use normally.